# How to position a Column inside the stack based on the fractional height of screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to position the `Column` inside the `Stack`, so that it takes 60% of the screen, and that it is positioned at the bottom of the screen.

```
////////
|
|
|40%
////////
|column
|
|
|
|60%
////////
```

Currently I am trying to do it with `Positioned` and with `MediaQuery` But It doesnt work.

```
      new Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6,

        child: new Column(
```

I know there are some Fractional Widgets that should help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with a Column widget (which is a subclass of a Flex widget) and Expanded children with the flex property.

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: [
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container() 
            ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```